# resurface interior concrete foundation wall

Tags: concrete, walls, foundation, resurfacing

Within the basement, the interior walls, where I have already pressure washed (4400 psi, 0° and 15° tip) after having used a stiff bristle brush and vacuum to first clean, then did etch & cleaner remove efflorescence which is the main cause of where I want to resurface.  The concrete aggregate (pebbles) are exposed and looks ugly.
The 4lb tub hydraulic cement I initially picked up I would need 5-10 more tubs of to cover everything that I want to.  Nothing would need more than  1/2" to 3/4" thickness of cement/mortar to make an acceptable looking surface, and this is just on flat vertical surface, no corners.  And there is no water seepage through the concrete.

what product can be used, that is offered in a 40+ lb pail or bag?  For example if I were to use an 80lb bag of concrete mix I would probably need about 2 to have enough to cover what I would want to get done including the typical crack filling.

Would standard mortar mix work?

Comment: The other possibility is to add a layer of insulation, and put a suitable interior wall surface over that, taking it partway to being a finished basement.  For a concrete wall, that's quite DIYable. (Unfortunately the other half of my foundation is old brick with lime mortar over fieldstone, which is much harder to do something reasonable with.)

Answer (score 2):

Ready mix stucco would work for that.

Maybe prep the concrete with liquid concrete adhesive to improve the adhesion.

You only need thin layer so no mesh is required.

However if you want to make it more humidity resistant apply  mesh with humidity barrier. They come already made for that, that would also improve the stucco adhesion and reduce cracking.

Best result would be to use 3 layers of stucco. Use scratch layer before applying the brown coat. The final layer can be a pigment or color.

If you are not into applying stucco, consider backer-boards. (best solution for tiles in bathrooms floors and walls.

Just screw then on the wall then cover the surface with what suits you. Backer-boards are moisture resistant, will not crack or bend. It will cost you more, but it is less work and the surface will be even.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is stucco mix. [stucco](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Rapid-Set-50-lbs-Stucco-Mix-13010050/202207960?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D22-022_009_CONCRETE-NA-NA-NA-SMART-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NEW-NA&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D22-022_009_CONCRETE-NA-NA-NA-SMART-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NEW-NA-71700000082416240-58700006970241162-92700062772249734&gclid=CjwKCAiA8OmdBhAgEiwAShr404hj1Q4HqS6nzJZt8cQWS4fbTL7caBzTzRBtQhYUJFx9Mcs2xp9vVRoCSZcQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)  You can add a latex additive for extra adhesion.
You can even "paint" the latex on the walls prior to the stucco, but it is a little pricy.  Concrete sealer over the dry stucco binds the fine particles and primes prior to painting on a final finish.